# Subversion and Netbeans - code formatting changes

Tags: java, svn, netbeans, commit, code-formatting

I have a small, technical problem with commits. Namely, when I'm going to make some changes in file I used to make an auto code formatting before I start to do anything (I like to work with clean code). The problem is, that svn diff will always show all these formatting stuff so it is difficult to find where the real, important changes have been made. One of the possible solution I am thinking of is to make an extra commit with "Code Formatting" comment, and next make the real modifications, but for me it is simply a kind of "empty and an least strange" commit.

How do you solve this problem (if you have it) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SVN clients usually you have "ignore white space" option in diff tool, which can help you look for "real" changes.

Anyway, changing formatting is not a good idea because of the reasons you described and that's why it is good to have one formatting policy in you company.